# MySQL ALTER TABLE increase column varchar size - 0 row(s) affected?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to test out MySQL alter table to increase varchar column size.
VARCHAR(50) -> VARCHAR(100)
I try to execute command -> ALTER TABLE profile CHANGE COLUMN username username VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;

MySQL response complete with 0 row(s) affected. How is that possible?
Shouldn't increase varchar size will impact all rows within the table?
I hope to know why MySQL can process this alter table command so fast.

[image: Result of table status]

Below is my table script, there are total of 9209 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
 `userprofileseqid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `clientdeviceseqid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `userid` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `username` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `usermobileno` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `userstatus` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `role` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `buscode` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `distname` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `distcode` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hqmobileno` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `otpsubmissionblocked` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `channel` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `createddate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `dealerstatus` VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dealername` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `userfullname` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`userprofileseqid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `userprofile_unique_index` (`clientdeviceseqid`,`userid`,`usermobileno`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I try on both MySQL version 5.7.20 & 8.0.28, both return 0 row(s) affected.
However, when downgrade the varchar size VARCHAR(100) -> VARCHAR(50), it will show 9209 row(s) affected without issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions. Please [edit] your question to include all the SQL statements you are running, including the one which create the table and insert the data.

Comment: Does the table have any data in it? What does `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'profile'` return in the `Rows` column?

Comment: yes! there are  9209 rows in the table, i attached the result in my post.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` report? I recall in some versions of MySQL, ALTER TABLE always reports 0 rows affected, regardless of the size of the table altered. In the current version MySQL 8.0, it reports the number of rows affected accurately. When I test the example ALTER TABLE you show, I get number of rows affected, equal to the number of rows in the table.

Comment: i see...my current version is -> 5.7.20

Comment: When you increase the length of the VARCHAR column then the value is NOT altered. When you decrease the length of the VARCHAR column then each value is checked does it must be truncated till newly specified length, hence all of them are affected. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html - *VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.* 100 or 50 chars - no difference.

Comment: I agree that the "0" verges on misleading.  If it bugs you enough, file a bug report ( bugs.mysql.com ).  However, it may get closed with "not a bug".  See Akina's Comment.

Comment: i see...thanks all, just curious on why no records changes by this command, and now i understand. =)