# Does MySql ALTER TABLE command affects rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table, error-log

I'm using query

```
ALTER TABLE `DEPLOYMENT` CHANGE COLUMN `ID_` `ID_` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
-> 72 row(s) affected Records: 72 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0  0.281 sec
```

But 2nd time while executing same query

```
ALTER TABLE `DEPLOYMENT` CHANGE COLUMN `ID_` `ID_` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL  
0 row(s) affected Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0  0.265 sec
```

Does it really affects the data?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285187/mysql-alter-table-increase-column-varchar-size-0-rows-affected . This should answer your question.

Comment: What's was the datatype of ID before changing to VARCHAR(100) ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha VARCHAR(64)

Comment: @SharathNS could you please highlight the response with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the length of a `VARCHAR` column doesn't need to modify any rows, unless the length changes from 1-255 to 256-65535. In that case it has to add a byte to the length field, which will affect every row.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused about response as it's saying 0 rows affected on 2nd try

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening. In my testing, if I went back and forth between different sizes, it would sometimes say 0 rows.

Comment: Yes, when we decrease and again increase the size it's giving the n affected rows but 1st onwards increases it's giving 0 affected rows and am not sure if there is any way we can see what's actually affected.